# Adding different parameter values in a single resource in Cloudformation- YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to combine two parameter values in yaml file and getting error.
One parameter has type as comma delimited values and another I am preparing using a combination of various params.
param1= endpoint1,endpoint2,endpoint3
param2= !Sub ${appname}.${env}.endpoint
Output expected: endpoint1,endpoint2, $param2

I need to pass both of these to create a listener rule in aws and both of these will be provided during execution when user fills the required information.

I tried something like:

```
- Field: host-header
  Values: 
    - !Ref param1
    - !Join
      - ','
      - !Sub ${appname}.${env}.endpoint
```

But above fails with error:

```
Template validation error: Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. The first parameter **must be literal string**, not any function. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html#intrinsic-function-reference-join-parameters):

> For the Fn::Join delimiter, you **can't use any functions**. You must specify a string value.